# Redirect PXE boot to normal boot

Tags: bios, pxe

I have a PXE server and few computers. Those computers have PXE boot enabled in the BIOS.

I would like to know if there is a way, from the PXE server, to tell the computers to boot normally (Linux) instead of continuing the PXE boot; without disabling the PXE boot on the BIOS.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new configuration in pxelinux.cfg folder, either MAC, IP (in hex) or portion of IP.

   > As an example, if the boot file name is pxelinux.0, the Ethernet MAC
   >   address is 88:99:AA:BB:CC:DD and the IP address 192.0.2.91, it will
   >   try following the files:
   >
   > ```
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/01-88-99-aa-bb-cc-dd
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/C000025B
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/C000025
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/C00002
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/C0000
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/C000
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/C00
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/C0
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/C
   > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default
   > ```
2. Then make it default or ontimeout to boot local drive

   ```
   LABEL BootLocal
           localboot 0
   ```

**Source:** [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki: PXE Install Multi Distro](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallMultiDistro)